# Unable to reach Canvas Element outside Handler method

Tags: java, gwt, canvas, handler, drawimage

Guys I've been trough a lot trying to figure what's wrong here. Finally i've found place where I stucked. The following code is snippet from my project, showing sole issue.
That's my EntryPoint Class:

```
import com.google.gwt.canvas.client.Canvas;
import com.google.gwt.canvas.dom.client.Context2d;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.madmax.client.gameservice.GWTService;
import com.madmax.client.gameservice.GWTServiceAsync;
import com.madmax.client.resources.ResourceManager;
import com.madmax.client.resources.images.cards.LandCardResources;


public class AltEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {


    public AltEntryPoint() {
    }

    public static GWTServiceAsync getService() {


        return GWT.create(GWTService.class);
    }
    private final Canvas canvas= Canvas.createIfSupported();
    private final Context2d ctx = canvas.getContext2d();



    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        final ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager(1000, 1000);
        Button b1 = new Button("Click", new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                                ctx.drawImage(resourceManager.getResourceCanvas().getCanvasElement(), 0, 0);
            }
        });

        resourceManager.loadImgResource(LandCardResources.INSTANCE.getHellHorseKnight(), "knight", 0, 0);
        resourceManager.loadImgResource(LandCardResources.INSTANCE.getMeadow(), "meadow", 150, 150);


        canvas.setWidth(500 + "px");
        canvas.setHeight(500 + "px");
        canvas.setCoordinateSpaceWidth(500);
        canvas.setCoordinateSpaceHeight(500);

                 RootPanel.get().add(resourceManager.getResourceCanvas());
                 ctx.drawImage(resourceManager.getResourceCanvas().getCanvasElement(), 0, 0);
                 RootPanel.get().add(canvas);
                 RootPanel.get().add(b1);

    }

}
```

and that's my ResourceManeger class

```
import com.google.gwt.canvas.client.Canvas;
import com.google.gwt.canvas.dom.client.Context2d;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.ImageElement;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.LoadEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.LoadHandler;
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ImageResource;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;


public class ResourceManager {

    private Canvas allImageHolderCanvas;
    private Context2d allImageHolderContext;

    public ResourceManager(int lengthDimension, int heightDimension) {
        allImageHolderCanvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
        allImageHolderCanvas.setWidth(lengthDimension + "px");
        allImageHolderCanvas.setHeight(heightDimension + "px");
        allImageHolderCanvas.setCoordinateSpaceWidth(lengthDimension);
        allImageHolderCanvas.setCoordinateSpaceHeight(heightDimension);
        allImageHolderContext = allImageHolderCanvas.getContext2d();
    }

    public void loadImgResource(ImageResource resource, String name, double sx, double sy) {
        final Image localImage = new Image(resource);
        localImage.setVisible(false);
        final String localName = name;
        final double sxVal = sx;
        final double syVal = sy;

        localImage.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
                allImageHolderContext.drawImage(ImageElement.as(localImage.getElement()),
                        0, 0, localImage.getWidth(), localImage.getHeight(), sxVal, syVal, 1000, 1000);
            }
        });

        RootPanel.get().add(localImage);
    }

    public void drawImageFromMetaDb(Context2d context, double sx, double sy, double sw,
            double sh, double dx, double dy, double dw, double dh){
        context.drawImage(allImageHolderCanvas.getCanvasElement(), sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
    }

    public Canvas getResourceCanvas(){
        return this.allImageHolderCanvas;
    }

}
```

Everything works perfect except one thing that already freaks me out.

ctx.drawImage(resourceManager.getResourceCanvas().getCanvasElement(), 0, 0);
doesn't work until it called inside Handler.

Please explain me where I'm wrong. Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ctx.drawImage(resourceManager.getResourceCanvas().getCanvasElement(), 0, 0);
> RootPanel.get().add(canvas);
> ```

Until the canvas is attached to the document (`canvas.isAttached()`, but attaching to the rootpanel will do that too), you cannot draw on it.

It also must have a size set on it, as resizing will adversely affect your content.

Reverse the order of those statements, and it should work as is. The reason that the load handler works is that by the time it is invoked, the canvas has been attached, so it is able to be drawn to.

Comment: No, i tried everything, and using methods like this :"canvas.rect(...); canvas.stroke();" instead if draw method works perfectly. Troubles begin only when using draw method. As a fix I can use Attach Handler and invoke this methods inside it. But I desire for explanation(

Comment: And yes, using draw method, works perfectly if invoked, after attachment. But previous mentioned methods are working before attachment as well.